# how to disable WM_ONPAINT message to be recieved by my window in C++ Builder?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, c++builder

i'am doing painting in another thread on my window and when my form recieves WM_PAINT (or WM_ERASE...) the form is erased to begin paint. I need to stop this message's from recieving by my window. How this can be accomplished?

This code just paint's current time and day of week in string type on main form when it recieves WM_APP+1 message.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::handleCustomMessage(TMessage &Message)
{

    static long id = 0;

    static DWORD sttick = 0;
    char tm[1024];
    DWORD curtick = GetTickCount()-sttick;
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetLocalTime(&st);
    static char sep[2] = ":";

    curtick = GetTickCount();
    if (curtick >= sttick+300)
    {
        sttick = curtick;
        sep[0] = (sep[0] == 0x20?':':0x20);
    }
    sprintf(tm, "%02d%s%02d%s%02d", st.wHour, sep, st.wMinute, sep, st.wSecond);
    // cnv->TextOutA(0, 0, tm);
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    // BeginPaint(hwnd,&ps);
    // if (!TextOutA(cnv->Handle, 0, 500, tm, strlen(tm)))
    // deb("textout: %s", fmterr());

    LOGFONT logFont;

    logFont.lfHeight = -(0.5 + 1.0 * Form1->Font->Size * 96 / 72);
    logFont.lfWidth = 0;
    logFont.lfEscapement = 0;
    logFont.lfOrientation = 0;
    logFont.lfWeight = Form1->Font->Style.Contains(fsBold) ? 700:400;
    logFont.lfItalic = Form1->Font->Style.Contains(fsItalic) ? TRUE:FALSE;
    logFont.lfUnderline = Form1->Font->Style.Contains(fsUnderline) ? TRUE:FALSE;
    logFont.lfStrikeOut = Form1->Font->Style.Contains(fsStrikeOut) ? TRUE:FALSE;
    logFont.lfCharSet = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
    logFont.lfOutPrecision = OUT_TT_PRECIS;
    logFont.lfClipPrecision = CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
    logFont.lfQuality = NONANTIALIASED_QUALITY; // 1
    logFont.lfPitchAndFamily = FIXED_PITCH;
    char str[2035];
    strcpy(logFont.lfFaceName, deunicode(Form1->Font->Name.c_str(), str, sizeof(str)));
    HFONT hFont = NULL, hFontOld = NULL;
    hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&logFont);
    if (!hFont)
        deb("failed to create font: %s", fmterr());
    // HDC dc = GetWindowDC(Form1->Handle);
    hFontOld = (HFONT)SelectObject(Form1->pb->Canvas->Handle, hFont); // 2
    // Form1->Canvas->TextOut(0, 0, tm);
    //
    Form1->pb->Canvas->Font->Color = clWhite;
    Form1->pb->Canvas->Brush->Style = bsClear;
    // Form1->pb->Canvas->TextOutA(1,1,tm);
    // deb("out %s",tm);
    SetTextColor(Form1->pb->Canvas->Handle, clWhite);

    RECT rect;
    rect.left = 0;
    rect.right = Form1->pb->Width;
    rect.top = 1;
    rect.bottom = Form1->pb->Height;
    // FillRect(Form1->pb->Canvas->Handle,&rect, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1));
    if(!TextOutA(Form1->pb->Canvas->Handle, 3,0,tm,strlen(tm)))
        deb("textout: %s",fmterr());
    //LockWindowUpdate(NULL);
    //int ret = DrawText(Form1->pb->Canvas->Handle, tm, strlen(tm), &rect, DT_CENTER|DT_NOCLIP|DT_EDITCONTROL);
    //if (!ret)
    //    deb("drawtext: %s", fmterr());
    // Form1->tedit->Text = tm;
    switch(st.wDayOfWeek)
    {
        case 1:
        strcpy(tm, "Понедельник");
        break;
        case 2:
        strcpy(tm, "Вторник");
        break;
        case 3:
        strcpy(tm, "Среда");
        break;
        case 4:
        strcpy(tm, "Четверг");
        break;
        case 5:
        strcpy(tm, "Пятница");
        break;
        case 6:
        strcpy(tm, "Суббота");
        break;
        case 7:
        strcpy(tm, "Воскресенье");
        break;
    }
    rect.top = Form1->Canvas->TextHeight(tm)+1;

    DeleteObject(hFont);
    logFont.lfHeight = -(0.5 + 1.0 * Form1->Font->Size * 96 / 90);
    logFont.lfWidth = 0;
    logFont.lfEscapement = 0;
    logFont.lfOrientation = 0;
    logFont.lfWeight = Form1->Font->Style.Contains(fsBold) ? 700:400;
    logFont.lfItalic = Form1->Font->Style.Contains(fsItalic) ? TRUE:FALSE;
    logFont.lfUnderline = Form1->Font->Style.Contains(fsUnderline) ? TRUE:FALSE;
    logFont.lfStrikeOut = Form1->Font->Style.Contains(fsStrikeOut) ? TRUE:FALSE;
    logFont.lfCharSet = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
    logFont.lfOutPrecision = OUT_TT_PRECIS;
    logFont.lfClipPrecision = CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
    logFont.lfQuality = NONANTIALIASED_QUALITY; // 1
    logFont.lfPitchAndFamily = FIXED_PITCH;

    strcpy(logFont.lfFaceName, "tahoma");

    hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&logFont);
    if (!hFont)
        deb("failed to create font: %s", fmterr());
    // HDC dc = GetWindowDC(Form1->Handle);
    hFontOld = (HFONT)SelectObject(Form1->pb->Canvas->Handle, hFont);
    //if(!TextOutA(Form1->pb->Canvas->Handle, 0,Form1->Canvas->TextHeight(tm)+1,tm,strlen(tm)))
    //    deb("textout: %s",fmterr());
    int ret = DrawText(Form1->pb->Canvas->Handle, tm, strlen(tm), &rect, DT_CENTER|DT_NOCLIP|DT_EDITCONTROL);
    if (!ret)
        deb("drawtext: %s", fmterr());
    // Form1->dedit->Text = tm;
    // SelectObject(dc, hFontOld);
    // ReleaseDC(Form1->tedit->Handle,dc);
    DeleteObject(hFont);
    SelectObject(Form1->pb->Canvas->Handle, hFontOld);
```

Comment: could you give us some details. I would comment that painting needs to be done in the main thread for a VCL app.

Comment: Not necessarily David, it can be done even from another process. Like DirectShow is painting video.

Comment: Yes, i am doing this in thread with Synchronize() function, but painting on canvas is thread-safe even without this. I just paint every time i got new data to draw, but i got flicker effect.After this i found that this is because of window recieving WM_PAINT or WM_ERASEBACKGROUND message and my thread has nothing to draw in about 100-200 msecs so the form is just erased.

Comment: painting on canvas is thread safe. I don't think so.

Comment: I think you'll need lots more detail including code to get any help

Comment: painting will work david but what will not is: if the thread does not get new data and does not repaint the old data non-stop anytime another window covers this one he will get garbage on the form canvas

Comment: I forgot where i read this but in embarcaderos help this is 100% that painting on canvas is really thread safe, but accessing main forms controls needs Synchronize(). I will post code here ok please wait

Comment: surely the paint message is posted to the thread which created the window?

Comment: yes the other thread just sending WM_APP+1 message every 200 msecs

Comment: This seems bizarre. Why do you need a thread? Why don't you have a timer and call InvalidateRect in the timer proc?

Comment: I'am doing some other manipulations in other thread with data, so i prefer to use thread not timer.

Comment: @Sergey Do you want to solve the problem or not? As soon as you start painting outside of WM_PAINT you are in trouble. It's trivial to do this in WM_PAINT. But if that's the way you prefer to do it, it's your call.

Comment: @David yes of course i need to solve this, but i need to paint at random times, not when i recieve WM_PAINT message. This is just one trouble i think... I need to block this message with WM_ERASEBKGND

Comment: if you need to paint just call InvalidateRect and them handle the ensuing paint message. If you ignore paint messages you will encounter blank windows and flicker.

Comment: DO NOT paint on a canvas from a separate thread!  It is NOT thread-safe.  The *correct* way to handle this is to have the thread draw its updates to an in-memory bitmap, then have the `WM_PAINT` handler draw whatever is currently in the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a WIn32 application then somewhere you will have similar code:
Look for my comments in the code.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_ERASEBKGND: // NOT ONLY ON PAINT BUT EVEN HERE
    case WM_PAINT:
            // DO NOTHING
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know CBuilder but Win32 apps all have a Window message handler. You must find how that is done and where in your form and catch thos two messages and do nothing.

Comment: Thanks Marino yes this is what i need, but i don't know how to DO_NOTHING in my function that will catch WM_PAINT and WM_ERASEBKGN because in C++ Builder it have no arguments and returns no values!

Comment: This is not true. You have FULL access to the message parameters and return values. Simply override the virtual `TForm::WndProc()` method. It is passed a `TMessage` structure, which contains the information. To "do nothing", simply do not call the base class `WndProc()` method.

Comment: -1 for not calling BeginPaint/EndPaint from a WM_PAINT handler.

Comment: Chris, not calling BeginPaint can be a design decision depending on what you need. In fact I have a movie player that not only doesn't call BeginPaint, it even calls ValidateRect on the whole area. You may ask why. Because another process is painting on the form and if another window would be moved over the form the standard window invalidation would create video artifacts. So you gave me a -1 for something I already knew very well and is not set in stone...

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the thread safety issues of C++ builder's canvas object...

You should always do your painting from the proper WM_PAINT method. While the window manager on Windows 7 can draw outside of BeginPaint/EndPaint, it invokes low performance code paths that exist purely for backwards compatibility.

Also, there are a number of asynchronous events that the user can trigger (by moving windows etc) that invalidate the area of a window, if the window is not updated by WM_PAINT then there will be a visible latency before the window is repainted.

The Desktop Window Manager (that implements Aero Glass) really requires that you use the proper way to redraw an animated window: use a timer that calls InvalidateRect to invalidate the area with the changing content: And simply handle WM_PAINT to handle the repainting of the new state.

Answer (score -1):

you could override the paint event conditionally with something like this

```
protected virtual void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
// Paint the control
// ...
// Raise the Paint event.
if (Paint != null)
Paint(this, e);
}
```

granted this is not c++ code, but the idea is that in C builder can you click on the events tab of the form and there should be an event called onPaint, once double clicked paint could then be disabled. I use Delphi and C++ Builder is same company so same ideas can apply. But this might not be the solution..

Generally the annoying thing with this is not the repaint as much as the repaint of the background which causes the flickering in the first place. You could enable use double-buffering on the form to prevent some flickering though. Or try to go for the erasebkgnd event and just fool windows into thinking it has been erased.

```
private:
void __fastcall WMEraseBkgnd(TWMEraseBkgnd &Message);
```

void __fastcall TParentForm::WMEraseBkgnd(TWMEraseBkgnd& Message)
{
   Message.Result = true; // We didn't erase the background but we tell Windows we did
}

Comment: in CBuilder i can't recieve paint arguments or return values. Or i dont know how to do that..

Comment: Thanks, wrote more on the answer.